# CSSStyleDeclaration.getPropertyValue("background-image") returns diferente in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, html

While I am working with CSSStyleSheet I need to retrieve a image URL.

The following command: `style.getPropertyCSSValue("background-image")` (where *style* is a *CSSStyleDeclaration*) returns `url("../../assets-common/images/planeta.png")` in Firefox, but returns 
`url(http://localhost:8080/assets-common/images/planeta.png)` in Chrome

In the real CSS file the path is a relative one. (as in Firefox)

Is there a framework or tool or script to make both explorers behave alike?

**NOTE:** I am accessing the CSSStyleDeclaration directly through CSSStyleSheet, I do not have a dom element to use getComputedStyle

Comment: It is a problem because I expect the same behavior in all the major browsers. My goal is to test the existence off all the background images in several stylesheets. (including images not used in the dom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use computed style, which give the absolute URL on both browsers.

In case the `CSSStyleDeclaration` does not belong to any element, you can style some element with that property and value, and get the computed one.

But if the stylesheet is external, in order to resolve the URL properly, you need a `base` element.

```js
function getCSSvalue(rule, prop) {
  var val = rule.style.getPropertyValue(prop), // Get the value
      ifr = document.createElement('iframe');  // Create iframe element
  document.body.appendChild(ifr);              // Load the iframe
  var doc = ifr.contentDocument,               // Document of the iframe
      url = rule.parentStyleSheet.href;        // Get the URL of the stylesheet
  if(url) {                                    // The stylesheet is external
    bas = doc.createElement('base');           // Create base element
    bas.href = url;                            // Set the base URL
    doc.head.appendChild(bas);                 // Insert the base in the iframe
  }
  doc.body.style
     .setProperty(prop, val, "important");     // Set the style
  val = getComputedStyle(doc.body)
       .getPropertyValue(prop);                // Retrieve the computed style
  document.body.removeChild(ifr);              // Remove the iframe
  return val;                                  // Return the value

}
getCSSvalue(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0], 'background-image');
```

Comment: I am not doing DOM manipulation. I do not have a element to call getComputedStyle upon. I get the CSSStyleDeclaration throught CSSStyleSheet

Comment: Unfortunately, as the Stylesheet is in a different directory than the HTML, this solution breaks the paths.

That being said, I do not understand why you use the color attribute. (and in my local environment it returns none always, but if i use prop variable like you did before you changed it, works , but with the path issue)

Comment: @Fernando Yes, color was a typo, it should be `prop`. Is the path of the stylesheet known?

Comment: I can get the path from the CSSRule, I am using cssRule.parentStyleSheet.href to retrieve the path, then I do some string splitting and concatenation magic to build the right path. But I was hoping for something less..... ugly (i am sore about browsers discrepancies)

Comment: sorry for the delay accepting your answer. Your answer does solve the problem.